# Use application/x-silverlight inside jquery.html()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, silverlight

I'm trying to use jquery.html() to change the content of a div.
It can recognize

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader id="m_objLoader" LoadFullProfileOfCurrentUser="true" runat="server"/>
```

But It cannot recognize

```
<SPSWC:ProfileBrowser webpart="true" runat="server" __WebPartId="{DCD5C686-342C-46C6-AD85-B2C2D27A6EAF}">
```

I've registered the following:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

But the Organization Browser won't be recognized, while in other pages it was fine.

Then I used

```
<object type="application/x-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight," id="ProfileBrowserSilverlightControl" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="top" value="30">
<param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true">
<param name="source" value="/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap">
<param name="initParams" value="username",User,ctl00_m_g_9d50a31d_3b6b_47c5_809c_cf68c257eb9b_ctl00">
<param name="windowless" value="true">
<param name="onLoad" value="__slEvent0">
```

Something appears, but in Fiddler, there's no query requering the

> SilverlightProfileService.json/GetUserSLProfileData

which usually works well.

Anyone has some clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the first one, because I cannot display anything with the HTML object way. If some one has some ideas about what's the problem, you are very welcome to tell me.

To avoid using jquery.html(), I integrated the Web Part directly in the page.
That's because when jquery.html() integrate the page into the orginal one, it won't inteprate the ***ProfilePropertyLoader*** because in the Web Part there's no ProfileProperty.